# Why was my scroll bar enabled on my HTML site?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am new in this field and now I am trying to improve myself by testing. I kept trying to figure out why I scroll bar vertically and horizontally, from what I noticed I think it's because of the tables. How can I solve this?
I know I didn't organize it very well, but I really want to solve that scroll bar, I also tried to hide it from the body, but if someone has a lower resolution, the total site will not be displayed. What do you think I could do to them?

```css
body
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-height: 100vh;
 background: #b3ccff;
 font-family: arcon;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* ------ [profesoreconomist.ro] ------ */
.link{
  left: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
/* ------ [Imagine Banner] ------ */
.banner{
position: relative;
top: 0;
margin-top: 4.3%;
right: -80px;
max-width: 1750px;
}
/* ------ [Continut butoane] ------ */
.spoiler {
  display: none;
  bottom: 50%;
}
.show {
  display: none; 
}
.hide:target + .show {
  display: inline; 
}
.hide:target {
  display: none; 
}
.hide:target ~ .spoiler {
  display: inline;
}
/* ------ [Buton Pagina Principala] ------ */
.btn { 
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forum-post1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  right: -58px;
}
/* ------ [Buton Curriculum] ------ */
.btn2 {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 29%;  
  padding: 10px 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forum-post2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -42px;
  left: 270px;
}
/* ------ [Buton Standarde de pregatire...] ------ */
.btn3 {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forum-post3 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  right: -435px;
  top: -84px;
}
/* ------ [Buton Prolectare didactica] ------ */
.btn4 {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forum-post4 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  right: -723px;
  top: -146px;
}
/* ------ [Buton Evaluare] ------ */
.btn5 {
  padding: 10px 27px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forum-post5 {
  position: relative;
  right: -963px;
  top: -188px;  
}
/* ------ [Buton Resurse internationale] ------ */
.btn6 {
  padding: 10px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forum-post6 {
  position: relative;
  right: -1085px;
  top: -210px;  
}
/* ------ [Buton Proiecte scolare] ------ */
.btn7 { 
  padding: 10px 8px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
} 
.forum-post7 {
  position: relative;
  right: -1273px;
  top: -232px;  
}
/* ------ [Buton Concursuri si olimpiade scolare] ------ */
.btn8 {
  padding: 10px 14px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  *background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  *border: 0;
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.forum-post8 {
  position: relative;
  right: -1410px;
  top: -254px;  
}
.spoiler-content {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 40%;
 right: 45%;
}
/* ------ [Meniu Pagina autentificare] ------ */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
  
@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)} 
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  /* ------ [Pozitie buton cancel din meniul de autentificare] ------ */
  .cancelbtn {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 100%;
  }
}
/* ------ [Buton Autentificare] ------ */
.login {
  padding: 13px 43px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #4d94ff;
  border: none;
   width: 200px;
 }
 /* ------ [Pozitie buton autentificare] ------ */
 .plogin {
  position: relative;
  top: -284px;
  right: -1669px;  
 }
 /* ------ [Buton Login din meniul de autentificare] ------ */
 .login2 {
    padding: 12.5px 43px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #4d94ff;
  border: none;
   width: 100%;
 }
button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* ------ [Buton cancel din meniul de autentificare] ------ */
.cancelbtn {
 left: 0%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  border: none;
}
/* ------ [Pozitie imagine din meniul de autentificare] ------ */
.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
  position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* ------ [Background meniu de autentificare] ------ */
.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* ------ [Continut meniu login] ------ */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; 
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; 
}

/* ------ [Buton X pentru inchidere meniu login] ------ */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  top: 0;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}
/* ------ [Tabel Noutati] ------ */
.tabel-noutati {
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  top: -270px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
/* ------ [Background alb tabele] ------ */
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  height: 550px;
  right: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
/* ------ [Text noutati] ------ */
.news {
  position: absolute;
 top: -2.5%;
 left: 15px;
}
/* ------ [Text link-uri utile] ------ */
.links {
 position: absolute;
 top: -2.5%;
 left: 15px;
}
/* ------ [Tabel link-uri urile] ------ */
.tabel-links{
 position: relative;
  left: 1399px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>xxxxxxx</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">

</div>
<body>
  <!------ Buton Pagina Principala ------>
<div class="forum-post1">
    <a href="#hide" class="hide btn" id="hide">Pagina principala</a>
    <a href="#show" class="show btn" id="show">Pagina principala</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Bine ai venit pe site-ul nostru!</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton Curriculum ------>
<div class="forum-post2">
    <a href="#hide2" class="hide btn2" id="hide2">Curriculum</a>
    <a href="#show2" class="show btn2" id="show2">Curriculum</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Continutul din Curriculum</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton Standarde de pregatire profesionala ------>
<div class="forum-post3">
    <a href="#hide3" class="hide btn3" id="hide3">Standarde de pregatire profesionala</a>
    <a href="#show3" class="show btn3" id="show3">Standarde de pregatire profesionala</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Standarde de pregatire profesionala</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton Prolectarea didactică ------>
<div class="forum-post4">
    <a href="#hide4" class="hide btn4" id="hide4">Prolectarea didactică</a>
    <a href="#show4" class="show btn4" id="show4">Prolectarea didactică</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Prolectarea didactică</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton Evaluare ------>
<div class="forum-post5">
    <a href="#hide5" class="hide btn5" id="hide5">Evaluare</a>
    <a href="#show5" class="show btn5" id="show5">Evaluare</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Continutul din Evaluare</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton Resurse internaționale ------>
<div class="forum-post6">
    <a href="#hide6" class="hide btn6" id="hide6">Resurse internaționale</a>
    <a href="#show6" class="show btn6" id="show6">Resurse internaționale</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Resurse internaționale</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton Proiecte școlare ------>
<div class="forum-post7">
    <a href="#hide7" class="hide btn7" id="hide7">Proiecte școlare</a>
    <a href="#show7" class="show btn7" id="show7">Proiecte școlare</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Continutul din Proiecte școlare</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton Concursuri si olimpiade scolare------>
<div class="forum-post8">
    <a href="#hide8" class="hide btn8" id="hide8">Concursuri și olimpiade școlare</a>
    <a href="#show8" class="show btn8" id="show8">Concursuri și olimpiade școlare</a>
    <div class="spoiler">
      <p class="spoiler-content">Concursuri și olimpiade școlare</p>
    </div>
</div>
  <!------ Buton catre link-ul profesoreconomit.ro------>
<a class="link" href="www.profesoreconomist.ro">profesoreconomist.ro</a>
  <!------ Buton de Autentificare / Meniul de autentificare ------>
<div class="plogin">
<button class="login" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Autentificare</button>
</div>
<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <img src="img\avatar.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="uname"><b>Numele utilizatorului</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Introdu numele de utilizator" name="uname" required>

      <label for="psw"><b>Parola</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Introdu parola" name="psw" required>
        
      <button class="login2" type="submit">Login</button>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Ține-mă minte
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Ai uitat <a href="#">parola?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
  <!------ Tabelurile de noutati si link-uri utile ------>
<table class="tabel-noutati">
  <tr>
  <th>
  <h2 class="news">Noutăți</h2>

<table class="tabel-links">
  <tr> 
  <th class="thh">
  <h2 class="links">Link-uri utile</h2>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a vertically stacked overflow menu like [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Responsive-Overflow-Off-canvas-Navigation-Plugin-With-jQuery-okayNav.jpg). However, you would need to use JavaScript to "listen" for the menu overflow button on-click event.

Perhaps look into grouping your menu items too, this can also save space. [example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_subnav.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a horizontal scroll bar, then wrap the contents in a div

> Home
>         News
>         Contact
>         About
>         ...

You can also customize it by using

> div.scrollmenu {
>         background-color: #ffff;
>         overflow: auto;
>         white-space: nowrap;
>       }
>
> ```
> div.scrollmenu a {
>   display: inline-block;
>   color: black;
>   text-align: center;
>   padding: 20px;
>   text-decoration: none;
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> div.scrollmenu a:hover {
>   background-color: white;
> }
> ```